# Error is running windows 10 over the virtual box

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, virtualbox, urban-terror

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows10.
>
> The virtual machine 'Windows10' has terminated unexpectedly during
>   startup with exit code 1 (0x1).
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: MachineWrap
>   Interface: IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}

and the second one is like this

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up
>   correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> as root.
>
> If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign
>   the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before
>   you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for
>   more information.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The
>   support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem, I'll try to explain below what I did.

First use

```
$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox
$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms
```

Next step: open bios setup, and security boot should be disabled.
Then install VirtualBox again via the terminal.

Comment: Yup, but my problem was not with virtual box, my secure boot was turned on